# Kellingham to Diapso

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At 10am, two hikers began walking, the first from Kellingham to Diapso, the second from Diapso to Kellingham along the same path. Each walk at a constant speed. They met at 1pm. The first hiker arrived at Diapso 2.5 hours before the second hiker arrived at Kellingham. When did the second hiker get to Kellingham?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: I tried setting up two equations using rate(time) = distance but didn't have any luck.

Comment: 2.5 hours after first hiker arrived at Diapso. :)

Comment: I wish it were that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will need this equation of the position of the Hikers $$\begin{cases}S_1(t) = v_1 t \\
S_2(t) = D - v_2(t)\end{cases}$$  (where $S_i$ means the position of Hiker $i$,  $v_i$ means the spead $D$ be the distance between the two cities
$T_1 = \frac{D}{v_1}$ (the time the first Hiker takes to end his journey is $T_1$ and $v_1$ is his velocity.) $T_2 = \frac{D}{v_2}$ $T_2 -T_1 = 2.5 h$

They meet at 1 pm : $3 v_1 = D - 3v_2 $

$$ 3h (v_1+ v_2) = T_1v_1\\
3h (v_1+ v_2) = T_2v_2$$
Let $v_2 = \alpha v_1$

$$3h (1 + \alpha) = T_1 \\
3h (1 + \alpha) = (T_1 + 2.5h) \alpha$$
Now put them together:
$$3h (1 + \alpha) = (3h (1 + \alpha) + 2.5h) \alpha $$

Simplify
$$3 (1 + \alpha) = (3 (1 + \alpha) + 2.5) \alpha  \Rightarrow \alpha = 2/3$$

So $\frac{T_1}{T_2} = \frac{v_2}{v_1} = \frac{2}{3}$

$$3 T_1 = 2 T_2 \\
T_1 = 2 (T_2 - T_1) = 5h \Rightarrow T_2 = 7.5 h$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the distance between the towns be  D . Let the speed of the faster traveller be  U , and of the other traveller, V . Let the time in hours be expressed as numbers,without units. After 3 hours,at 1 p.m.,they meet, so [1]: 3U + 3V = D , which gives [2]: V = U - D/3 .  Now the total times for the trip are  D/u and D/V,  so [3]: D/V - D/U = 5/2 . Substitute the value for V in [2] into [3] and multiply out the denominators in the equation. The resulting equation is quadratic in U, and its positive solution is [4]: U = D/5.  Putting U = d/3 into [2] gives [5]: V = 2D/15.  So U/V = 3/2. Therefore,if the faster one spent time T , the slower one spent time 3T/2.  The difference, 5/2 (hours) is  3T/2 - T = T/2. So T = 5. And the rest is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

It is more convenient perhaps with a distance-time juxtaposing graphs to put down relations:

$$ \dfrac{b}{a} = \dfrac {3}{3+t} = \dfrac{t}{3+2.5} $$

obtained by proportioning similar triangles, leading to a quadratic equation:

$$ t^2 + 3 \,t -16.5 = 0, $$ with approximate solutions $ t= 2.83, -5.83 $  hours. Latter solution is discarded.

Time taken by the slower person is 2.83 + 3 + 2.5 = 8.33 hours...

and faster  person takes 2.83 + 3 = 5.83 hours, 2.5 hours less.

The distance $a$ need not be known in absolute terms.

The graphical procedure bonus advantage is that it gives not only when, but also where ( distance $b$ ratio ) the two  meet.

[image: OppositeDirnWalk]